# Nothing happened when I alert using jquery in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

`Jquery/Javascript` are not working in **codeigniter**. What i did is

In `config.php` I include

```
$config['javascript_location'] = 'libraries/javascript/jquery.js';
$config['javascript_ajax_img'] = 'images/ajax-loader.gif';
```

In `controller/welcome.php` I include

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('javascript');
        $this->load->library('javascript/jquery');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $data['library_src'] = $this->jquery->script();
        $data['script_head'] = $this->jquery->_compile();

        $this->load->view('register', $data);
    }
```

In `views/register.php` I include

```
<?php $this->jquery->click('#username', $this->jquery->alert("hi")); ?>
```

But nothing is happened. No error displayed. How can I make `jquery/Javascript` events in `Codeigniter`. Question related to this are asked by others but i can't find a solution yet. So don't marked this as duplicate.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

**Any alternative way(any way) for working jquery in CI. Simply how can i make work jquery in CI.**

Comment: Why you combine js and php. what is $this->load->library('javascript');
        $this->load->library('javascript/jquery');

Comment: @RakeshSharma, from http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/javascript.html i got this. When i use $this->load->library('jquery'); this i got the error unable to load the requested class jquery

Comment: is there any way to work jquery in codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to use jQuery as javascript not the version included with codeigniter because it my be an old version you can but your javascript libraries in new folder called **asset/js** on root of project

and include them in view as follows

```
<html>
     <head>
          <script src="<?=base_url()?>/assets/js/jquery.js" type="text/javscript"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#username").click(function(){
               //your code here
          });
     });
</script>
     </head>
```

Comment: thanks, but not working..can i include jquery.1.8.3.js and write the code. I tried but not working..Is there any way to work jquery

Comment: check console in chrome devTools wheather there is an error and tell me the result

Comment: when i use base_url, a blank page obtained.

Comment: do you set the value of $config['base_url'] in config?
if not set it to the "http://yourserver/yoursite/"

Comment: yes like this,  $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter/'; and in view page  like this , <script src="<?=base_url()?>/js/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javscript"></script>

Comment: if you can  I can help you via teamviewer

Comment: ohk, now in console:  Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined , this error is displayed

Comment: And i put as <script src="<?php echo base_url('js/jquery-1.8.3.js'); ?>" type="text/javscript"></script> not like in your code

Comment: this error displayed in console because jquery didn't included correctly

Comment: can you send me the generated script tag in your html